# How to stop repeating imageview on scroll?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a imageview and a textview in listview. So i  am dynamically changed tick mark or without tick mark image.

Please suggest me how to save  ticked image position after scroll.

Comment: here is my code http://notepad.cc/share/Q8AHDqIIy9

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want? Can you clarify? Also please add the code to your question, instead of posting an external link.

Comment: Brother i have two images 1)with Right mark and 2) without Right mark . so i  am replacing  without Right mark to with Right mark by click an item from listview than i am scroll the listview but after that i got without Right mark image. but i want save that place insort not refresh that

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301250/adding-image-to-listview-after-listview-item-click

Comment: So basically you want to retain ListView information after scroll. You can use a integer array containing the image for every position for the ListView. eg- `int[] image = new int[]{R.id.checked, R.id.unchecked,....}`. Then, when you change the image on ListView `ItemClickListener`, change the value of the image array by `image[position] = R.id.unchecked;`. Android will automatically change the images then.

Answer (score 0):

Inflate the item view with null ViewGroup.

```
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_dialog_list,
                        null);
```